# Overwrite css for checkbox

Tags: css

I would like to overwrite the default checkbox css. The checkbox is generated by ASP.NET MVC @Html.CheckBoxFor. How to resolve this issue using css? the following code is not working

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
}
```

Comment: show your generated `@Html.CheckBoxFor` are you sure that there is a container with `.checkbox` class?

Comment: yup i have solve the problem. checkbox for generate additional html  hidden input after checkbox